# How to prevent video preview popup in IOS for html videos

Tags: html, ios, video, popup, preview

I have 5 videos in home page of my website, http://stg.ionhealingapp.com/. All videos are playing perfectly in all screen sizes. I have disabled controls and muted the video to start the autoplay.  But, the only issue is with iPhone. When ever I am trying to play the videos other than the first video, the video is popping up and controls are visible. I don't want this to happen.

I can see that there is an option to disable "Auto-play video previews" from iOS13.

https://ios.gadgethacks.com/how-to/disable-auto-playing-video-previews-your-iphone-ios-13-0198401/

But couldn't find option to disable this in iOS12 and in earlier versions.

This is my video tag:

```
<video width="320" height="240" muted loop>
  <source src="link to my video" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Is there any option to disable the preview popup from HTML end/iOS end?

Comment: as far as i know in ios when pressing to watch the videos they open automatically with the commands and it is not possible to untangle it; /

Comment: Are you building an iOS app and opening the videos inside a WKWebView, or you're talking about the Safari from the iPhone that opens your website with the videos?